# Why can we determine the pos/neg chirped or un-chirped of linear chirped pulse in the spectrum of frequency resolved optical gating method?

Tags: laser

In SHG Frequency Resolved Optical Gating experiment(FROG), the two copies pulses with delay in one of them are sent into a SHG crystal(for second harmonic generation). I take SHG FROG in Wiki as my reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency-resolved_optical_gating

We can get a spectrogram in terms of time delay and frequency. Why can we determine the properties of linearly chirped pulse by looking the oblique form of the spectrogram? What is the relationship or mechanism between them?

Edit:
Oblique form of spectrogram:
[image]

(This picture is from https://www.brown.edu/research/labs/mittleman/sites/brown.edu.research.labs.mittleman/files/uploads/lecture17.pdf)

Comment: What do you mean by "we determine the chirp" and "oblique form of spectrum", please, elaborate.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

Think of a "negatively" chirped pulse as being the impulse response of a linear filter whose frequency transfer characteristic is $$H_1(f+f_0) = p(f)e^{-\mathfrak j \pi \beta f^2}$$ where $p(f)=1 \text{ if } |f|<W \text{ and } p(f)=0 \text{ if } |f|>W$. Obviously, this is a bandpass filter centered at $f_0$. In its bandpass has constant amplitude characteristic but its phase characteristic $\phi(f)$ is a quadratic function of frequency. Therefore, its group delay is $$\tau_1(f)=-\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{d\phi}{df} = \beta f$$ inside the pass band centered at $f_0$.

The "positively" chirped pulse is the impulse response of the filter $$H_2(f+f_0) = p(f)e^{\mathfrak j \pi \beta f^2},$$ with $p(f)$ and $\beta$ are the same as before. This filter's group delay is obviously $$\tau_2(f)=-\tau_1(f)=-\beta f .$$
Say, you prepare an impulse $\delta (t)$ as the input of the filter $H_1(f)$. Since the Fourier transform $\delta(t)$ is $1$ the output time function is the inverse Fourier Transform $h_1(t)$ of $H_1(f)$. This is actually a *chirp* signal in the sense that its instantaneous frequency is a linear function of time aside within a time varying envelope caused by the bandpass nature of the filter.
It is a linear chirp because the delay that each frequency component at $f+f_0$ of $\delta(t)$ suffers is exactly $\beta f$ so that the higher frequencies are delayed relative to the lower ones. Similarly, the impulse response $h_2(t)$ of $H_2(f+f_0)$ is also a linear chirp but now its frequency components are advanced by $\beta f$ so that the higher frequencies are ahead of the lower ones.

Now take $h_1(t)$ as the input of $H_2(f+f_0)$ then the output is the same as the impulse response of $H_1(f+f_0)H_2(f+f_0)$ which is the cascade of the filters $H_1$ and $H_2$. But $H_1(f+f_0)H_2(f+f_0) =p(f)$ whose impulse response is just an bandpass filtered impulse, a pulse whose effective length is the reciprocal of $W$. That is pulse compression. So first a wideband impulse is converted to nearly constant envelope wideband signal and that is passed through a filter whose group delay is exactly the opposite of the filter preceding it. The result is a narrow pulse whose width is inversely related to the bandwidth of the filters but otherwise it is a near replica of the input pulse within the bandwidth $W$.

In reality, because of causality you cannot have a *negative* group delay. But the sum of the two group delays can be some positive constant within the pass band where that positive constant represents the total transport delay through the two filters.

Comment: Thank you for your reply